# VectorDrawables slowing down RecyclerView, not loading into ImageView when using libraries

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-image

I didn't know what to put as a title because this is kind of a strange problem so I will edit it if anyone has a better idea.

In my application I have a RecyclerView which needs to be populated with some images. Those images are VectorDrawables imported by right click on drawable folder -> new -> vector asset -> local file (svg, psd).

Those images are saved as an array local_images_array.xml file like this:

```
<integer-array name="images_array">
    <item>@drawable/img1</item>
    <item>@drawable/img2</item>
    <item>@drawable/img3</item>
    ...
</integer-array>
```

I am getting them as TypedArray and putting their resource ids in a model class ArrayList like this:

```
private TypedArray images;
private List<ModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();
...
images= getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_array);

for (int i=0; i<images.length(); i++) {
    ModelClass modelClass= new ModelClass();
    modelClass.setImg(images.getResourceId(i, 0));

    modelClassList.add(glogenaItem);
}
```

All of this is done in my Activity class. After that, in my Adapter class, I populate the views in onBindViewHolder like this:

```
holder.imgView.setImageResource(modelClassList.get(position).getImg());
```

This works as intended, it loads the images into imgView, but scrolling the list is really lagging on my galaxy s5 mini, and even crashes on some other devices with outOfMemoryException.

It lags for a few seconds and after that I see no lag at all so I thought maybe it needs some time to load and tried things described on these links:
 - https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
 - https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html
But with that it lags even more and it doesn't stop lagging with time, it just lags forever.

After that I tried using Picasso and Glide libraries but those ran into a different kind of problem. They do not load images into imgView at all, they just leave an empty space. I also tried loading those images in Glide's and Picasso's placeholder() method and they load just fine in it, but scrolling lags just as bad as it did when I was using code from those two links above, so placeholder is not a good solution.

Someone told me that he had the same problem with lag and tried UniversalImageLoader and it worked perfectly with no lag at all so I went to try it myself but I ran into the same problem as with using Glide and Picasso, it does not load images into imgView.

I did however notice that it prints this message into logs:

```
E/ImageLoader: Image can't be decoded [drawable://2130837820_248x248]
```

This is what I find strange about this problem, because why would native setImageResource method load images normally but libraries are unable to do the same. So i googled this error and only thing I found is that I should call this method on ImageLoaderConfiguration class:

```
.imageDecoder(new NutraBaseImageDecoder(true))
```

I tried it but nothing happened, error is still present.

I also spotted another log message:

```
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
```

This one shows twice between every UniversalImageLoader error so my logs look like this:

```
11-23 02:05:20.908 6993-7096/com.fabula_croatica.glogena E/ImageLoader: Image can't be decoded [drawable://2130837820_248x248]  
11-23 02:05:20.920 6993-7097/com.fabula_croatica.glogena D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null  
11-23 02:05:20.922 6993-7097/com.fabula_croatica.glogena D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null  
11-23 02:05:20.923 6993-7097/com.fabula_croatica.glogena E/ImageLoader: Image can't be decoded [drawable://2130837820_248x248]  
11-23 02:05:20.955 6993-7099/com.fabula_croatica.glogena D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null  
11-23 02:05:20.958 6993-7099/com.fabula_croatica.glogena D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null  
11-23 02:05:20.958 6993-7099/com.fabula_croatica.glogena E/ImageLoader: Image can't be decoded [drawable://2130837820_248x248]
```

I tried to google that one as well but the only thing I found about it is that it shows when you try to load something that is not an image. I don't see why my vector drawables wouldn't be considered images since they do load with setImageResource so they are not corrupted or anything.

I hope someone can get something out of all this mess and understand what is going on and how to fix this.

Comment: What size are the VectorDrawables and are they simple or complex?

Comment: They were around 900x900dp at first, I resized them to be around 24x24dp but there was no difference. If you ask about file size, since they are saved as xml files they are around 40kb. Don't really know what is the difference between simple and complex but I would go with complex since they have multiple <path/> tags, some of those with different colors. But I also tried loading google's own icons which usually have only one <path/> and the problem was still present.

Comment: Huh, I would expect a problem with 900x900dp, the docs recommend no higher than 200x200dp for vector drawables. If the problem is still present with the small icons as you say, then I'm not sure.